# How to split and then join comma separated words into a string to create condition?

Tags: c#

I have given words like:

> general, sports, weather

I want to create a push notification condition like:

```
condition = "'general' in topics || 'sports' in topics || 'weather' in topics",
```

How can I do this in one -or two- shot in C# without looping? So I can build a new string and I use it like below:

```
condition = dynamicCondition,
```

Comment: Why the "without looping" constraint? You're going to have to iterate over the words anyway, either with loops or using Linq or other methods that hide this iteration. What have you tried? Also, what does "condition like" mean? Is your desired output a string, or runtime logic?

Comment: I know how to build dynamic condition string using loop in ie c# 2.0. I want to learn if there is better and modern way.

Comment: What is a "dynamic condition string", and how would you build one using C# 2.0? Your question is really unclear.

Comment: Please can downvoters explain me their causes?

Comment: You actually don't need loops or Linq, just string functions:  `"'" + string.Join("' in topics || '", names.Split(",")) + "' in topics"`

Comment: just for fun: `condition = "'" + names.Replace(", ", "' in topics || '") + "' in topics"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```csharp
string input = "general, sports, weather";
string output = string.Join(" || ", input.Split(',').Select(s => $"'{s}' in topics"));
```

Note: don't forget to `using System.Linq`

Comment: You don't have to delimit single quotes in a string.